# invalid json response body - Headless SSR mode

Tags: jss

Followed the steps in the below link to setup the headless SSR mode https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/ssr/headless-mode-ssr

but it the app never comes up and always received an error saying

### *invalid json response body at https://poc-app/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/JssReactWeb/en?sc_apikey=%12345%7D reason: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0', type: 'invalid-json' }*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps in the link https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/ssr/headless-mode-ssr

But additionally the dictionary service end point needs to be updated in the proxy application's config.js

Search for JssReactWeb and replace with your app name.

Comment: We're updating the docs to reflect this in https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/pull/108

Comment: That's great....